# Join lines based on the first field patern

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, vi

I have a file with 200,000 lines. The begining of each line starts with "IMAGE", "HISTO" or "FRAG". I need to join lines HISTO and FRAG to the IMAGE line. Here is an example.

```
IMAGE Lots of Data on this line  
HISTO usually numbers 0 0 1 1 0 1 0  
FRAG Always at least 1 of these lines but can be more
```

The result needs to look like this:

```
>IMAGE Lots of Data on this line HISTO usually numbers 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 FRAG Always at least 1 of these lines but can be more
```

It is possible to have many FRAG lines before it starts over with an IMAGE line. I am using mac so I can use pretty much any tool, but I am much most familiar with vi.

Comment: @James Brown the first solution worked well. The modified version leaves a space before the fist line. No biggie, but I have to remove it in excel or my columns get mixed up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWK:

```
awk '/^IMAGE/&&NR>1 {print a; a=""} {a=a""$0" "} END{print a}' test.in
```

Out loud:

```
/^IMAGE/ && NR>1 { # if it starts with IMAGE
    print a        # empty buffer variable to output
    a=""           # reset the buffer after emptying
} 
{                  # for all records
  a=a""$0" "       # append to the buffer variable, prob. no need for ""
}
END {              # in the end
  print a          # empty the remaining buffer in the end
}
```

Comment: Use `next`, don't test all values.